# Asserting text of element with &nbsp

Tags: mocha.js, chai, cypress

I need to check the text of a Div tag and ensure if it is showing the correct text of not

here is the HTML Code:

[image: HTML Tag]

Here is the step definition i wrote to assert the content

```
    Given(/^offer summary section should display "([^"]*)" amount against "([^"]*)"$/, (charge, labelText) => {
    const parentElement = cy.get('.c-offer-summary > .c-offer-summary__ledger').children('.c-ledger__section').find('.c-ledger__row-name').contains(labelText).parent();
    parentElement.find('.c-ledger__row-amount').invoke('text').should('eq',charge);
});
```

But cypress is throwing an error:

[image: Error]

I am not sure where i am going wrong !!! :(

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 15):

Based on [Maccurt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2178421/maccurt)'s assertion (which gives more context to the assertion information printed in Cypress logs) and [Hiram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9161752/hiram-k-hackenbacker)'s replace function, I composed this assertion.

```js
cy.get(".c-ledger__row-amount").invoke('text').then((text) => {
    expect(text.replace(/\u00a0/g, ' ')).equal('DKK 15.00');
});
```

It works well on my case. Here's a screenshot for the assertion result:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could use Cypress's `.contains()` command which strips whitespaces:

```js
cy.get('.c-ledger__row-amount').contains('DKK 15.00')
```

Or you can remove the space character then assert:

```js
cy.get('.c-ledger__row-amount')
  .invoke('text')
  .invoke('replace', /\u00a0/g, ' ')
  .should('eq', 'DKK 15.00')
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to to test that .c-ledger__row-amount is "DKK 15.00". Try this.

```
cy.get(".c-ledger__row-amount").invoke('text').then((text) => {
         expect(text.trim()).equal('DKK 15.00');
});
```

Sometimes you have to remove the trailing spaces

Comment: helpful note but this doesn't solve the OP's issue as there are no trailing spaces in the DOM screenshot attached