# Cannot get text as in GUI

Tags: javascript, cypress, non-breaking-characters

I have some amounts which I need to display. The amounts needs to be hovered and then they would show.

For example an amount may be `+123 456,33` but in the code it is showing as like `+123NNSP456,33`.
Now when I  write my test, I am having to put

```js
cy.get('.total-month').should('contain.text','+123NNSP456,33')
```

so that the test passed.  If I test for what is being showed in the GUI like this

```js
cy.get('.total-month').should('contain.text','+123 456,33')
```

it is not identifying the amount.

This is the html:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] this question to type the text from the image so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 4):

[Using a similar strategy to Jennifer's answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65178203/11625850) you can use `invoke` to replace the text value.

```
cy.get('.total-month')
  .invoke('text')
  .invoke('replace', 'NNSP', ' ')
  .should('contains', '+123 456,33');
```

The tl;dr is that your   character is interpreted as `NNSP`. Replacing that with a traditional whitespace character should solve your problem.

Comment: Actually, `.should('eq', '+123 456,33')` will fail - there is also a Euro symbol + some line breaks. I think `.should('contains', '+123 456,33')` is better.

Comment: You're absolutely right -- I was looking too closely at the other SO post. I'll edit mine to reflect that.

Comment: i tried i am getting
the below: 
`invoke
.replace( , )
assert
expected '' to include -123 456,33 € `

Comment: Just i replaced NNSP to NNBSP

Comment: Just to add when i copy the text from the DOM it does not show the NNBSP but it shows it when i copy it to my ide

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `replace` method to replace `NNSP` with an empty string.

```js
cy.get('.total-month')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => {
    expect(text.trim().replace('NNSP', '')).to.equal('+123456,33')
  })
```